# Error with paypal sandbox account during testing of payment

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, sandbox

I want to implement paypal IPN at my website. For that purpose I created 2 paypal sandbox accounts of type business (seller) and personal (seller) through my paypal developer account. Thereafter I created buy now button at my paypal sandbox business account with item name, code, price etc. and generated a code for buy now button, pasted it on my website. For first 2 weeks testing work smoothly after it started giving errors like

> Sorry we cannot complete your purchase at this time. Please return to the merchant and choose other way to pay

Hence again I created 2 separate sandbox accounts, again same problem happened after 2 weeks. What is the reason behind this type of errors and how to rectify it?

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeees, someone help please. My whole project stopped because of that security robot. I messaged the support, the community but no answers. in addition I can't create, delete any more sandbox accounts

Comment: [I got my problem solved today](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/sorry-we-can-t-complete-your-purchase-at-this-time-error/m-p/1351533). it took about 30 hours to get fixed. however I can't delete the sandbox accounts with error created at the problem time

Comment: same here even I cannot delete sandbox accounts with errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error is mainly due to using same credit card or banking account at buyers sandbox account.One need to use different credit card and bank account for too many test transaction performed through sandbox accounts.

Comment: Yes me too noticed the problem happened after testing with credit cards .