# PayPal checkout form stopped working - but no code changed on our end

Tags: php, paypal

I have a Paypal form that stopped working, seemingly of its own accord, with no changes made to the site or to the products on sale. We've tried PayPal support but they were of zero help, so I'm hoping somebody here will know what's going on.

This is the form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://www.example.com/images/logo.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="coins_RqQC0rdyH87RlYt7bkZI3GXS">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypalaccountemail@example.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/en/thankyou.php?order_code=seriea_RqQC0rdyH87RlYt7bkZI3GXS">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.example.com/en/choose-account-type">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="50 coins">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="16.99">
    <input type="image" src="/images/paypal-button3.png" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

As I said, the code or products haven't changed, so I'm stuck. If you're wondering why "item_name_1" etc, it's because we have a shopping cart which allows multiple things to be purchased in the same checkout process. I have some ideas which I've been unable to verify:

1) PayPal changed things on their end without letting us know, making the code obsolete?

2) Hosting company changed the server's IP, new SSL certificate - perhaps additional action needed in our PayPal account for this reason?

3) I'm missing something obvious and will feel stupid following the first comment on this question.

Comment: "*We've tried PayPal support but they were of zero help*" ... god I've been there all too often. Also "*stuff just stopped working when it was ok*" is a normal trend too! ... sorry, I have no tips here.

Comment: The code might be didn't change,  but the merchant account settings could be changed. There are lots of possibilities, may be if you defined what do you mean by  *"stopped working"* that could narrow the possibilities.

Comment: Sorry about that. The message PayPal provided was so vague that it felt useless to add it to my question here. What you get when you submit the form is a PayPal page that just says "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.". And it's been like that for at least a week.

Comment: I know it's very upsetting. I had [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123718/error-with-paypal-sandbox-account-during-testing-of-payment) with them too and it took about 2 days till it's resolved and about 1 week till the support respond on my email, but they were very helpful and friendly when they responded. Test with different products and check the account settings, also try to create new buttons and test them, that may give you some insights.

Comment: About *"PayPal changed things on their end without letting us know, making the code obsolete"* I don't think they will destroy all that compatible codes around the world this simply.